# C# Listener to detect automactically new incoming SMS on GSM Modem using AT commands

Tags: c#, ajax, gsm, modem, at-command

I'm developing a web application using c# to send and receive SMS from GSM modem by using AT commands.

Sending and receiving is working fine. Receiving the SMS is working on button click event, but I want whenever new SMS comes program should show it automatically.

Comment: I guess you'll need to poll the SMS inbox and update your web page using AJAX. Maybe add sample code from your receive button event handler to illustrate your current solution.

Comment: how can i detect new message using AT+CNMI..

Comment: Well, how to detect new messages you should have already solved in your receive button click event (at least you claim in your initial question). I'm no expert in AJAX or AT commands in .NET but I think you should be able to put something together. Maybe rephrase your question to ask how to turn your receive button event handler code to a AJAX polling control. People here will be more likely to help you if you don't expect them to give you ready solution - show us what you have tried.

Comment: i fired the command AT+CMGL="ALL" by which i can get all the sms stored in sim card..one thing i can do that i can make a thread which will fire this command after a given interval, that method i dont want to use, Here is command AT+CNMI which give me indication when new message comes, i just want to implement this command, means when modem receives a message this command will fire and give me a response i just want to capture that response, but dnt know how can i do this...

Comment: I solved the issue...Thanks Filburt i got a important point from your comment...

Comment: hi may i get your idea how did you solve your problem

Comment: @Sandeep How to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't require any thread you just need define datarecieved event which will be automatically fired when ever new message arrives. and you can use it's handler to read message.

You need to set

```
serialport1.DtrEnablle = true;
serialport1.RtsEnable = true;
```

Considering you have enabled notifications using

```
AT+CNMI=1
AT&W
```